# Testing with PostgreSQL in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to switch my Rails TEST environment from SQLite3 to Postgresql.

However, when I run

```
rake spec:requests
```

this error is generated:

```
omar@loco:~/apps/gctest$ rake spec:requests
rake aborted!
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]

Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am able to access the DB in Development (my database.yml file for test looks similar to development but with _test).

**Are there any gotchas that I'm unaware of?
what does the "Tasks:..." line mean?**

My env:

```
rspec (2.6.0)
rails (3.0.9)
ruby 1.9.2p290
pg (0.11.0)
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion that you do not have the `test` key in your `database.yml` file and Rails is attempting to use that and not finding it. However, I could be wrong. That does look like that kind of issue though.

What does `--trace` at the end of that command make it output extra? Perhaps you could update the question with that output to help us?

Comment: You nailed it, I just realized that right after I posted then came back to delete this post.. I had copied "Development:" twice! ...thanks!